# Pandas - value changes when adding a new column to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column to a dataframe using the following code.

```
labels = df1['labels']
df2['labels'] = labels
```

However, in the later part of my program, I found that there might be something wrong with the assignment. So, I checked it using

```
labels.equals(other=df2['labels'])
```

and I got a `False`. (I added this line instantly after assignment)

I also tried to

1. print out part of `labels` and `df2`, and it turns out that there are indeed some lines that are different.
2. check max and min values of both series, and they are different
3. check number of unique values in both series using `len(set(labels))` and `len(set(df2['labels']))`, and they differs a lot
4. test with a smaller amount of data, but this works totally fine.

My dataframe is rather large (40 million+ lines), so I cannot print them all out and check the values. Does anyone have any idea about what might lead to this kind of problem? Or is there any suggestions for further tests?

Comment: `df1['labels'].isin(df2['labels']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang got some True and some False :(

Comment: can you try labels = df1['labels'].copy() on the first line?

Comment: @d_frEak also not working :( I also tried to set `copy(deep=True)`, not working either

Comment: can you try to compare it with df1['labels'] too? so you can start by knowing actually which one is correct between labels and df2['labels] or the worst case you have 3 different labels series

Comment: @d_frEak oh, all these 3 are different... Even if I added copy everywhere. That's strange

Comment: I think we can not really doing anything because we don't have details of your source code, it can be caused by some inplace function that changes the content directly or something else

Comment: @d_frEak yes I think so too, especially when this is actually part of a quite large project... I'm not sure which other parts are relevant and thus cannot provide more code. Maybe I should check the other code. But still thanks a lot! :)